# add hair particles to vertex group only

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

So, I've created a vertex group and a hair particle system. I only want the hair particles on the vertex group. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your vertex group in the Density Tab in Particle Settings

[image]